# Помогите разобраться с кодом задачи с Codewars (C99)

Tags: c

Начал решать задачи с Codewars. Задача следующая
У некого товарища есть от `m` до `n` злотых. Если он купит 9 машин стоимостью `с` злотых каждая, то у него останется 1 злотый. Если он купит семь лодок стоимостью `b` каждая, у него останется 2 злотых. Нужно найти все варианты в которых перечислено количество денег, стоимость машин и стоимость лодок в формате строки подобного рода.

```
howmuch(1, 100) => [["M: 37", "B: 5", "C: 4"], ["M: 100", "B: 14", "C: 11"]]
```

Решение я написал следующее

```
char *howmuch(int m, int n) 
{
    char promezh[1000];
    char var[1000];
    char *rez = var;

    snprintf(var, 1000, "[");

    for (; m <= n; m++)
        {
            for (int c = 1; c <= m; c++)
                {
                    for (int b = 1; b <= m; b++)
                        {
                            if ((m - 9 * c) == 1 && (m - 7 * b) == 2)
                                {
                                    snprintf (promezh, 1000, "[M: %d B: %d C: %d]", m, b, c);
                                    strcat (var, promezh);         
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
    strcat (var, "]");
    return rez;
}
```

Код который вызывает эту функцию для тестов такой

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

char* howmuch(int m, int n);

void dotest1(int m, int n, char *expr)
{
    char *act = howmuch(m, n);
    if(strcmp(act, expr) != 0)
        printf("Error. Expected %s but got %s\n", expr, act);
    cr_assert_str_eq(act, expr, "");
}

Test(howmuch, ShouldPassAllTheTestsProvided) {
    {
        char* ans1 = howmuch(1, 100);
        char* sol1 = "[[M: 37 B: 5 C: 4][M: 100 B: 14 C: 11]]";
        dotest1(1, 100, sol1);
    }
    {
        char* ans1 = howmuch(0, 200);
        char* sol1 = "[[M: 37 B: 5 C: 4][M: 100 B: 14 C: 11][M: 163 B: 23 C: 18]]";
        dotest1(0, 200, sol1);
    }
    {
        char* ans1 = howmuch(1000, 1100);
        char* sol1 = "[[M: 1045 B: 149 C: 116]]";
        dotest1(1000, 1100, sol1);
    }
}
```

В итоге я получаю лог

```
Time: 694ms Passed: 3 Failed: 1
Test Results:
 howmuch
 ShouldPassAllTheTestsProvided
Test Passed
Test Passed
Test Passed
 Log
Error. Expected [[M: 9991 B: 1427 C: 1110]] but got []
The expression (as strings) (act) == (expr) is false.
Completed in 687.174805ms
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, где этот четвертый тест в коде, который я не могу пройти. Или я получаю ошибку по иной причине? Почему я не могу его пройти, учитывая, что при запуске этой функции в Visual Studio Code со следующими аргументами howmuch(9900, 10000) я получаю правильные ответы.

P.S. **Run sample test** прогоняет только три варианта.
Ссылка на задачу вот https://www.codewars.com/kata/how-much/train/c

Comment: Если тестово вы получаете правильный отчет на п.4, а система вас не пропускает, значит что-то вы не учитываете. Возможно ваш алгоритм работает дольше чем можно, или требует памяти больше чем можно. Или есть что-то о чём вы не знаете.

Comment: В том то и дело, в коде задачи я не вижу условий при которых я должен получить строку [[M: 9991 B: 1427 C: 1110]]. А Run Sample Test прогоняет только три описанных в коде (которые видно). Если бы алгоритм работал дольше чем надо, меня бы об этом уведомили (ограничение 1200ms).

Comment: очевидная ошибка — ты возвращаешь указатель на данные выделенные на стеке... кроме этого ты грязно используешь `strcat ()`, а сам алгоритм малоэффективный, хотя для небольших входных значений работать и должен.